# android services to get current location

Tags: android, geolocation, location

I have started work on app that requires user's current location. I looked for some services for this. I got Android Location Service ([link1](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html), [link2](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)) and [skyhook](http://www.skyhookwireless.com/) sdk. Does anyone know which one is better and stable? Please recommend me one.

Comment: This one is best

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Answer (score 1):

For receiving location info you can use standard api (your link1 and link2). But strategies of receiving depends on what you need, get location or listen location. 
You also can look at this [android training](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html). In this training you can see how to use new Location api provided by Google in google services lib. This lib provide a lot of features details of which you can find [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bte_GHuxUGc).
 If you have simple location acquiring logic - best way to use standard apis (like in link1 and link2).